# Untrack tracked file in Git -- but only in specific branch?

Tags: git, version-control

Originally, I had everything contained in my master branch.

Then, I decided to split into Mac and Windows branches, and have the master branch only track the source code files. So I began to only stage changes to source code files when in the master branch, and merge those source code changes with the Mac and Windows branches as needed.

Problem is, when I originally tracked everything in my master branch, I had tracked the project file as well. Thus, I would be adding new files to the project and getting it compiling in Mac and Windows, but upon switching back to the master branch, the project file would be switched back to the old version as well, causing compilation to fail.

So how can I stop tracking my project file in the master branch *now*? I don't want to stop tracking it in my Mac or Windows branches, and I don't want to remove it from earlier versions  in the master branch either.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
git rm --cached projectFile
```

Will delete the file in the index, so it will no longer be tracked, but won’t physically delete it.

Comment: Aha, thanks! Will this untrack for only the current branch, or for all branches?

Comment: Only for the current one; just like `git add`.

Comment: Aha, interesting. Unfortunately, whenever I switch to the master branch, the project file is removed as well. Can I get it to only change the files it's tracking?

Comment: Hmm, I’m not sure if that’s possible as switching branches always first removes all files tracked in the old branch and replaces it by the files in the new branch. So the file would only stay there, if it wasn’t tracked in your branch either, which isn’t what you want I think. Maybe you could give the `master`’s project file (or even better, the platform specific ones) a different filename?

Comment: @wrongusername: Branches point to commits. Anything uncommitted is, well, uncommitted. Staged changes, like the deletion created by `rm --cached`, are staged, not committed - so they're not tied to branches. Just like untracked files and local modifications, they can sit there intact when switching branches. (I think this explains some of the confusion you had.)

Comment: Out of curiosity - if in branch master he did `git rm --cached projectFile` then `echo projectFile >> .gitignore` then `git commit -am"stopped tracking on master"` would not this achieve what he wanted ? Or would merging master to Windows/Mac delete the projectFile from those branches ? He could always cherry pick commits from master to avoid this but yeah...

Comment: Yes, if the file was not tracked on any of the branches, then it wouldn’t be removed, but could be kept around locally.